# Correct usage of lifecycle hooks in Aurelia component

Tags: google-maps, aurelia

I'm working on integrating Google Maps into a Aurelia component. The component will use one-way binding to get its data (from the parent View) which it then will draw on the map. Both Google Maps (`MapsAPI`) and the data (`this.statistics`) is loaded async.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489802/remote-service-in-aurelia-component-lifecycle) question it seems that the `attached` method is the best fit - and that's what I'm currently using. However as can seen from the code below I'm calling upon the `drawMap` in both `attached` and `statisticsChanged`. I am worried that I could risk calling the draw method twice (based on what is loaded first, the maps-api or my data).

Is there a *cleaner / more correct* way to ensure that all data is loaded? Ideally I'm looking for something like the `activate` method found in Controllers.

```
constructor(MapsAPI, GeoService) {
    this.mapsApi = MapsAPI;
    this.geoService = GeoService;
}

attached() {
    return this.mapsApi
        .then(mapsApi => this.google = mapsApi)
        .then(() => this.extendGoogleMaps())
        .then(() => {
            this.startPoint = new this.google.LatLng(1,1);
            this.finshPoint = new this.google.LatLng(2,2);
            this.bearing = this.google.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(this.startPoint, this.finshPoint);

            if (this.canDraw()) { 
                this.drawMap(); // I'm a bit worried this might be called twice, see statisticsChanged
            }
        });
}

canDraw() {
    return (this.statistics && this.statistics.length > 0);
}

drawMap() {
    _.forEach(this.statistics, (data) => {
        data.coordinates = this.createCoordinatesForTeam(data);
    });

    this.initMap(this.statistics);
}

statisticsChanged() { // Called twice somehow. 
// First with undefined, second time with actual data
    if (this.canDraw()) {
        this.drawMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is undefined in "// First with undefined, second time with actual data"? And what is your concern about calling draw method twice: is there functional issue or efficiency concern?

Comment: statisticsChanged is called whenever this.statistics changes as expected. However even though it's defined as null both in the component and the parent view, it's called with this.statistics as "undefined" once the component loads. As for the drawing twice method; yes there are performance concerns (or at least, UX concerns).

I have partially solved this problem by re-wiring the parent view, but the question is still valid as a concept.

Comment: So the first `statisticsChanged()` is no problem, thanks to `canDraw()`. If maps-api data is loaded first, it's also no problem, again thanks to `canDraw()` still return `false`. It's only a problem when statistics data is loaded first. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct. But you are missing the point: The question isn't how to get it working, it's whether Aurelia has any functions / design patterns for when you need data both through binding and from an injected dependency.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood that you need a life cycle to ensure both data are loaded, which sounds strange. Essentially, you need a way for the component to delay working until it finishes internal initialization. Something like `activate` would be perfect fit. The component would still not be able to have any control over the binding data (`statistics`), and a validation method like `canDraw` is still necessary.

Comment: You could try pushing the maps initialisation to the back of the task queue, that way any pending bindings will be run before the maps component is initialised. This is also an approach which you can take if you have DOM elements based on repeats or if bindings and you want to make sure they are present in the DOM before you initialise a 3rd party plugin like a jq component

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there are no lifecycle hooks that allow you to wait for the data.

In v1 all the lifecycle hooks ignore Promises, that is even though in your `attached` you are returning a Promise Aurelia will continue on with its processing regardless.

The `activate` method for [The Route Screen Activation Lifecycle](https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet#routing) does accept Promises, but even then I'd discourage returning one as it causes you to block until it has completed. It is better to deal with the async nature and provide user feedback in your component that it is not yet ready.

There are probably some decent React documents on the web that give you a flavour for how to handle async data requirements.

Essentially you should be building you component so that it can handle zero data and to do the right thing.

Then set up your component to call `drawMap` every time any of the data it depends on changes.

Put your guards into `drawMap` to stop it drawing until all the dependencies have been provided. Your component should react to data changes rather than procedurally calling things.