# When in Aurelia lifecycle should I populate component properties?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, lifecycle

I have an Aurelia component that has some property (a list of items) that I want to initialize from an API call. That list of items will ultimately show up in a *select* element. While that list is empty, I'm okay with showing an empty *select* (or disabling it).

My question is, when in the [component lifecycle](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3) should I populate the list of items? I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35490468/1370556) which suggests `attached`. But I was thinking that, since it doesn't really depend on the component being attached or bound, that I would just do it in the constructor.

What are the advantages, disadvantages and repercussions?

### component.js

```js
@inject(WebApi)
export class MyComponent {

  api = undefined;
  items = undefined;

  /**
   * Creates the component
   * @param api the web API
   */
  constructor(api) {
    this.api = api;
    this.api.getItems().then(items => {
      this.items = items;
    });
  }
}
```

### component.html

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <select value.two-way="selectedItem">
      <option repeat.for="item of items" model.bind="item">${item.id}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general recommendation, I would not do this in the constructor. This goes for any code you're writing, no matter the framework or language. A constructor should do the minimal amount of work necessary to set up an object and then return. Granted, you are using a promise here, so the constructor will still finish quickly, so there is an argument to made that this is okay here.

That being said...

The callback you would use will depend on the use-case. You have three choices for a component that isn't loaded by the router: `created`, `bind`, and `attached`. In your use case, you are okay with disabling the select element until the data is loaded, so using the `attached` callback is fine. I personally would probably put this call here.

If the data was needed before databinding, I would use the `created` callback. If the data being retrieved required a parameter that is received via databinding, I would use the `bind` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the response! One question, if I return the promise in `attached`, wouldn't that slow things down because Aurelia is now waiting for the response to attach to the DOM? What happens if I do the API call in `attached` but don't return the promise?

Comment: If you don't return the promise, then Aurelia keeps moving along. This is a good thing as you have the choice of waiting or not waiting.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find any documentation about returning the promise. When I try it in my code, the elements get attached without waiting for my returned promise to resolve.

Comment: The `attached` callback is called after the element has been attached (thus the past tense in the callback name).

Comment: Oh I see, of course! Also, I don't think Aurelia does anything with returned promises in the lifecycle callbacks: https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/367. You would have to use the [CompositionTransaction](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/templating/latest/class/CompositionTransaction).

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. I've been known to be wrong once or twice.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the info about promises :-)

Comment: In v1 the component lifecycle does not wait for Promises to return.
In v2 all the lifecycle hooks are meant to support Promises.

However, in v1 the Router lifecycle does support Promises, so `activate` can fetch data and wait until the Promise returns.

see https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/order-of-components-lifecycle-between-components-plus-router/2947/11